# sails + waterlock, how to implement the workflow with corresponding HTML templates

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, waterlock

## Background

About 6 months ago, I started developing a web app with Sails. 
I was hoping to easily implement Authentication and Permission using `sails-auth` or `sails-generate-auth` and `sails-permissions`. 6 months later I realize that these modules aren't well maintained anymore. I decided to fall back using `Waterlock`.

## Questions

> I am newbie when it comes to **NodeJS, Express & Sails**. Coming from **Rails**, I had biased expectation. I need to be taken by the hand...

I was able to install **Waterlock** properly, and was able to play with the API.

### 1. Login

POST http://localhost:1337/auth/login

Passing `email` and `password` in the `form-data` (See screenshot bellow):

which returned (in POSTMAN):

```
{
  "auth": {
    "password": "$2a$10$5swWYJLZ.KbKWA9.8Hg8eOr.8HiCBiddWDyHyGSB3y7bluJZwvjDS",
    "email": "my.email@mydomain.com",
    "createdAt": "2016-10-04T13:01:17.594Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-10-04T13:01:17.607Z",
    "id": 12,
    "user": 13
  },
  "createdAt": "2016-10-04T13:01:17.603Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-10-04T13:01:17.603Z",
  "id": 13
}
```

I guess my user was created and stored along with his encrypted password.

[image]

**Next** I tried implementing the UI (that's where I need guidance):

`UserController.js`:

```
'new': function(req, res) {
    res.view();
},
```

`user/new.ejs`:

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<form action="/auth/login" method='POST'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='me@mydomain.com' name='email'>
    <input type='password' placeholder='password' name='password'>
    <input type='submit' value="Create account">
</form>
```

**Question 1**: After create/login the user i.e. `auth/login`, how do I redirect to another URL? *e.g.* `/user/show/:id` **id** of the user just created.

I tried adding the `login` action the `AuthController`, but that just overrides the actual useful action.

> **UPDATE**: I found that `waterlock.js` has Post actions hooks, but still don't know how to redirect to `/user/show/:id` of the user just created or logged in.

**Question 2**: Shouldn't I remove the `"password": "$2a$10$...ZwvjDS",` returned?

### 2. JWT

Alright, **JSON Web Tokens**. So I am authenticated, and next I create a JWT that I can pass in the header of my next request.

With POSTMAN

POST http://localhost:1337/user/jwt

```
{
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIxM3x1bmRlZmluZWQiLCJzdWIiOiJzdWJqZWN0IiwiYXVkIjoiYXBwIG5hbWUiLCJleHAiOjE0NzYxOTIxNDc3OTgsIm5iZiI6MTQ3NTU4NzM0Nzc5OCwiaWF0IjoxNDc1NTg3MzQ3Nzk4LCJqdGkiOiI5ODgyYWY2MC04YTM1LTExZTYtODI0Yy1mNTZhYWE0MDhiZmIifQ.GYT4f49ggW8VwaEqTy0JskX6nHWZUMvM0A92KD1EC4I",
  "expires": 1476192147798
}
```

**Question 3**: I am authenticated, a session was created right? Why do I need a JWT? Is it better than `sessionAuth`?

Actually found my answer [here](https://float-middle.com/json-web-tokens-jwt-vs-sessions/)

**Question 4**: Right after LOGIN, I need to `POST http://localhost:1337/user/jwt` to obtain a JWT. How should I implement that in Sails?

### 3. How do I how use my `access_token`

**Question 5**: Where do I store the `access_token` and use it in the next request ? (the best practice for Sails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad. 2)** Certainly yes. Client shouldn't have access to his encrypted password

**Ad. 4)** JWT should be in service, no controller, because is more secure way. So, yep. It should be done in server side and client shouldn't have access to JWT logic.

**Ad. 5)** Whatever you want. IMHO header is best place.